# Problema con prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, prestashop, paypal

Tengo un problema con mi prestashop a la hora de acceder al back-office y es que al intentar entrar me devuelve esta excepción:

```
[PrestaShopDatabaseException]
 MySQL server has gone away


  SELECT `id_module` FROM `pshop_module` WHERE `name` = "paypal" LIMIT 1

     at line 635 in file classes/db/Db.php
     629.           WebserviceRequest::getInstance()->setError(500, '[SQL 
   Error] '.$this->getMsgError().'. From '.(isset($dbg[3]['class']) ? 
 $dbg[3]['class'] : '').'->'.$dbg[3]['function'].'() Query was : '.$sql, 
 97);
 630.       }
 631.       else if (_PS_DEBUG_SQL_ && $errno && 
 !defined('PS_INSTALLATION_IN_PROGRESS'))
 632.       {
 633.           if ($sql)
 634.               throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this- 
 >getMsgError().'<br /><br /><pre>'.$sql.'</pre>');
 635.           throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError());
 636.       }
 637.   }
 638. 
 639.   /**
 DbCore->displayError - [line 325 - classes/db/Db.php] - [1 Arguments]
 DbCore->query - [line 547 - classes/db/Db.php] - [1 Arguments]
 DbCore->getRow - [line 572 - classes/db/Db.php] - [2 Arguments]
 DbCore->getValue - [line 2229 - classes/module/Module.php] - [1 Arguments]
 ModuleCore::getModuleIdByName - [line 1929 - classes/module/Module.php] - 
 [1 Arguments]
 ModuleCore::isInstalled - [line 131 - modules/paypal/paypal.php] - [1 
 Arguments]
 PayPal->__construct - [line 1031 - classes/module/Module.php]
 ModuleCore::getInstanceByName - [line 463 - classes/Hook.php] - [1 
 Arguments]
 HookCore::exec - [line 2357 - classes/controller/AdminController.php] - [2 
 Arguments]
 AdminControllerCore->init - [line 163 - classes/controller/Controller.php]
 ControllerCore->run - [line 373 - classes/Dispatcher.php]
 DispatcherCore->dispatch - [line 54 - admin/index.php]
```

Como digo no puedo acceder al back office y no encuentro la solución a este problema. He intentado deshabilitar el módulo de paypal desde la BD pero se mantiene el problema.

Agradezco toda ayuda

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Como bien comentas, esta claro que es tema de paypal, haz lo siguiente como truco, elimina la carpeta paypal de modules, en caso de que siga igual, mediante ftp sube la carpeta paypal nueva, por ejemplo descargada de addons prestashop a la carpeta modules.

https://addons.prestashop.com/es/pago-tarjeta-carteras-digitales/1748-oficial-de-paypal.html

Cuando consigas entrar ya puedes poner todo en orden. Espero que te sirva, saludos.